# In Search Of: a noun (or phrase) like "irrefutableness"

Tags: single-word-requests

Ideally I'm looking for a word, though it could be a phrase.  It should be a noun, like "veracity".

Its somewhat close in meaning to veracity.  It should mean low likelihood of being refuted. Sort of like being "authoritative" on a subject, but not as certain as that.

I intend to use include it in a sentence like: These improvements give our information product a greater X.

I can elaborate if that would be helpful.

Thank you!

**ADDED**

I don't think veracity ("truthfulness") is the right word.  It's not a matter of our telling the truth.  It's a matter of the likelihood of whether the information presented is sufficient to prove something.

**ADDED**

Our information product speaks about having observed certain data and presenting an accurately preserved, complete and untampered with record, which is why "authoritative" didn't work.  (In theory, there could be relevant unrecorded data.)  Also, because of this, "authenticity" isn't the issue since there's no reason to doubt the authenticity of our data.

(And I certainly wish the context allowed me to be cheeky enough to say "truthiness"!)

Comment: Do you mean *authenticity?* http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/authenticity

Comment: or *evidence*? Which is basically the proof and the pudding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*incontrovertibility* and *incontrovertibleness*, *indisputability* and *indisputableness*, *incontestability* and *incontestableness* -- essentially the same meaning as *irrefutability* and *irrefutableness*.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Drew!  I wasn't able to come up with a single word for my initial thought on phrasing, so I'm going with a phrase including the more down to earth sounding "uncontestable", rather than "incontestable".  (Some online dictionaries don't include uncontestable and I suspect it might be slang, but I can live with that for this piece.)  While our presentation could be contested, we don't believe any contest would be successful. 
"These features bolster our product's ability to present a uncontestable complete and accurately preserved record."

Comment: Update: Changed the word we are going with to "unimpeachable".  With this word we are not using the potentially slang "uncontestable", however with unimpeachable we are retaining the notion that someone could call it into question, but we believe such question will fail.